# Can data be stored anywhere else on a MacBook besides the SSD?

Tags: hardware, storage, data-recovery, ssd, macbookpro

Imagine the following scenario: There exist all kinds of information on my SSD. Now I take away the SSD of my MacBook Pro, replace it, and reboot. I should have a MacBook that is on factory settings, right?

I am wondering if there is any way, or hardware, where information from my old SSD can be found, whether in parts or full? If yes: is there any limitation to what type of information it can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is other writable storage on the system like chips for storing the bios or other firmware. These are usually just a few MB so you can't store everything from your SSD on there. But enough to safe interesting stuff. AFAIK some user settings are also stored in the NVRAM like WiFi names.